# How I filter a # on a search bar in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, filter

I need to filter a list in wordpress. I have a list of companies and Iwant to search the name and the company is filter on the top of the page. On the search I put the name and the list item is show on the same page. Don't know anything of php. I need help, I'm very frustrated.

Comment: "A problem well defined is half solved": If you would define the problem better for us, you would find the solution much more easily.

Comment: You're asking us to do your work for you, which we won't. It doens't sound like you've tried anything yet, you'd be better to come back and ask for help when you've tried something, and have something to show possibly

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just resolve the problem. Thanks anyway.